# How to pass a single member array of an array of structs to function to perform linear search

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to perform a linear search on just one member array of an array of structs that has 3 members.

I want it to just search for the house number but I can't figure out the syntax.

If it was just a single array, I could do it and if it was just a struct then I could do it but because it is an array of structs, I struggle.  Can you help me with my function header and call?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Build
{
    int number;
    string size;
    char wall_type;
};

int searchArray(const int [], int);


int main ()
{
   int result,                // Index of array that matches search
       value;                // The house number entered by user

   Build house[5] = {
                       {1, "big", 'F'},
                       {3, "small", 'D'},
                       {5, "tiny", 'A'},
                       {7, "huge", 'B'},
                       {9, "medium", 'F'}
                    };

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)              // Just a test to see if the 
   {                                       // array is populated correctly
       cout << house[i].number << "  "
            << house[i].size << "  "
            << house[i].wall_type << endl << endl;
   }

   cout << "Enter the house number:  ";
   cin  >> value;

   result = searchArray(house.number, value);

   if (result == -1)
       cout << "Not found." << endl;
   else
   {
      cout << "Index number:  " << result << endl
           << "House number:  " << house[result].number << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}


/***************************************************************
 *
 *   This function searches an array of integers to find a match
 *   entered by the user.  It works great if you are just dealing
 *   with a single array but I can't figure out the syntax to 
 *   search just one member of a struct in an array of structs.  
 *   Please help!
 *
 */

int searchArray(const int list[], int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    int position = -1;

    while (index < 5 && !found)
    {
        if (list[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Rather use a `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of c-style arrays.

Comment: Can't you just change your int searchArray(const int list[], int value) int searchArray(const Build &list[], it value) ?

Comment: `list[index].number == value`? And of course use Marco's change first.

Comment: Also, watch yourself when `using namespace std;`. `list` is a type in the standard library, so if it ever gets included in your project, it should conflict with your variable name. Even if it doesn't, it would look weird.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marco and James for catching that.  This helps tremendously.  Also, thanks for the heads up James about list. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with call. You cannot pass only house.number. You can pass to the search function:

- whole array of Builds (and adjust search function properly to the Build's structure)
- new array of ints only (you have to create one)

and then you can perform the search. For me above should not even compile.

You can try:

```
int intArray[5];

for(int iter=0; iter<5; ++iter){
    intArray[iter] = house[iter].number;
}

int result = searchArray(intArray, value);
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.  I will go with your first suggestion